# 'ul li' hover color with hyperlink inside

Tags: css

Consider:

```css
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
}

ul li {
  border-radius: 7px;
  line-height: 21px;
  padding: 0 9px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

ul li a {
  color: #555;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: #0099cc;
  color: white;
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='titlewrap'>
  <ul>
    <li class='title'><a href='view.php?id=1' target='_blank'>lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li class='title'><a href='view.php?id=2' target='_blank'>lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li class='title'><a href='view.php?id=3' target='_blank'>lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li class='title'><a href='view.php?id=4' target='_blank'>lorem ipsum</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hovering, `li a` color is changed to white, but when I move the pointer outside of `a` and still inside of `li`- color is again `#555`.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ul li a` is more specific than `ul li:hover`.
Rather have the nested anchor tag inherit its `color` from its containing list item tag.

```
ul li a {
    color: inherit;
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
}

ul li {
  border-radius: 7px;
  line-height: 21px;
  padding: 0 9px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

ul li a {
    color: inherit;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: #0099cc;
  color: white;
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='titlewrap'>
  <ul>
    <li class='title'><a href='view.php?id=1' target='_blank'>lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li class='title'><a href='view.php?id=2' target='_blank'>lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li class='title'><a href='view.php?id=3' target='_blank'>lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li class='title'><a href='view.php?id=4' target='_blank'>lorem ipsum</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Currently, you're setting color with `ul li a`, which has higher specificity than `ul li:hover`.

I believe what you're looking for is `ul li:hover a` instead of `ul li a:hover`.

```css
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
}

ul li {
  border-radius: 7px;
  line-height: 21px;
  padding: 0 9px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

ul li a {
  color: #555;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: #0099cc;
  color: white;
}

ul li:hover a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='titlewrap'>
  <ul>
    <li class='title'><a href='view.php?id=1' target='_blank'>lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li class='title'><a href='view.php?id=2' target='_blank'>lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li class='title'><a href='view.php?id=3' target='_blank'>lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li class='title'><a href='view.php?id=4' target='_blank'>lorem ipsum</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead

```
ul li:hover a {
  color: white;
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
}

ul li {
  border-radius: 7px;
  line-height: 21px;
  padding: 0 9px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

ul li a {
  color: #555;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: #0099cc;
  color: white;
}

ul li:hover a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='titlewrap'>
  <ul>
    <li class='title'><a href='view.php?id=1' target='_blank'>lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li class='title'><a href='view.php?id=2' target='_blank'>lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li class='title'><a href='view.php?id=3' target='_blank'>lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li class='title'><a href='view.php?id=4' target='_blank'>lorem ipsum</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line too in your CSS:

```
ul li:hover a{
    color: white;
}
```